# vuejs2 event listening not working

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-component, vue-router

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-tutorial and trying to develop my laravel admin panel using vuejs.
Filter in the list vue is not working

This is my list.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <filter-bar></filter-bar>
        <vuetable ref="vuetable"
          api-url="/api/category/list"
          :fields="fields"
          pagination-path=""
          :css="css.table"
          :sort-order="sortOrder"
          :multi-sort="true"
          detail-row-component="my-detail-row"
          :append-params="moreParams"
          @vuetable:cell-clicked="onCellClicked"
          @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
        ></vuetable> 
        <div class="vuetable-pagination">
          <vuetable-pagination-info ref="paginationInfo"
            info-class="pagination-info"
          ></vuetable-pagination-info>
          <vuetable-pagination ref="pagination"
            :css="css.pagination"
            :icons="css.icons"
            @vuetable-pagination:change-page="onChangePage"
          ></vuetable-pagination>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

import VueEvents from 'vue-events'
Vue.use(VueEvents)
var Vuetable = require('vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable.vue');
Vue.use(Vuetable);
var VuetablePagination = require('vuetable-2/src/components/VuetablePagination.vue');
var VuetablePaginationInfo = require('vuetable-2/src/components/VuetablePaginationInfo.vue');

Vue.component('custom-actions', require('../CustomActions.vue'))
Vue.component('filter-bar', require('../FilterBar.vue'))
export default {
  components: {
    Vuetable,
    VuetablePagination,
    VuetablePaginationInfo,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      fields: [

        {
          name: 'id',
          sortField: 'id',
        },
        {
          name: 'name',
          sortField: 'name',
        },

        {
          name: '__component:custom-actions',
          title: 'Actions',
          titleClass: 'text-center',
          dataClass: 'text-center'
        }
      ],
      css: {
        table: {
          tableClass: 'table table-bordered table-striped table-hover',
          ascendingIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
          descendingIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'
        },
        pagination: {
          wrapperClass: 'pagination',
          activeClass: 'active',
          disabledClass: 'disabled',
          pageClass: 'page',
          linkClass: 'link',
        },
        icons: {
          first: 'glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward',
          prev: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left',
          next: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
          last: 'glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward',
        },
      },
      sortOrder: [
        { field: 'id', sortField: 'id', direction: 'asc'}
      ],
      moreParams: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {

    onPaginationData (paginationData) {
      this.$refs.pagination.setPaginationData(paginationData)
      this.$refs.paginationInfo.setPaginationData(paginationData)
    },
    onChangePage (page) {
      this.$refs.vuetable.changePage(page)
    },
    onCellClicked (data, field, event) {
      console.log('cellClicked: ', field.name)
      this.$refs.vuetable.toggleDetailRow(data.id)
    },
    onFilterSet (filterText) { 
        this.moreParams = {
            'filter': filterText.trim()
        }
        Vue.nextTick( () => this.$refs.vuetable.refresh())
    },
    onFilterReset () {
        this.moreParams = {}
        Vue.nextTick( () => this.$refs.vuetable.refresh())
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.$events.$on('filter-set', eventData => this.onFilterSet(eventData))
      this.$events.$on('filter-reset', e => this.onFilterReset())
  }

}
</script>
<style>
.pagination {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}
.pagination a.page {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.pagination a.page.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.pagination a.btn-nav {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.pagination a.btn-nav.disabled {
  color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.pagination-info {
  float: left;
}
</style>
```

Filter in the list vue is not working

This is my FilterBar.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="filter-bar ui basic segment grid">
    <div class="ui form">
      <div class="inline field">
        <label>Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="filterText" class="three wide column" @keyup.enter="doFilter" placeholder="name, nickname, or email">
        <button class="ui primary button" @click="doFilter">Go</button>
        <button class="ui button" @click="resetFilter">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      filterText: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doFilter () {
      this.$events.fire('filter-set', this.filterText)
    },
    resetFilter () {
      this.filterText = ''
      this.$events.fire('filter-reset')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Event is being fired in the filterbar vue component, but listener in list.vue component doesn't pick it up

I tried the fix in the issues tab
1.using method and mounted
2.using created

Comment: Please, check in this addon https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd in 'Events' tab did ur event emitting properly

Comment: @GONG This is my event info  name:"vuetable:loaded"
type:"$emit"
source:"<Vuetable>"
payload:Array[1]
0:undefined